# gradient of trace$(ABA^TC)$ w.r.t a Matrix A.

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, vector-analysis

With n-order Matrix A,B,C.I was trying to find $ \nabla_A trace(ABA^TC)$

This answer:[Proof for the funky trace derivative : $d (\operatorname{trace} (ABA'C))$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138267/proof-for-the-funky-trace-derivative-d-operatornametrace-abac/138618#138618)

suggested:
$$
\nabla_A \operatorname{trace}( ABA^{T}C )  = CAB + C^T AB^T
$$

with a implication that 
$$\nabla_A AB = B^T$$

can somebody show me why?

I also have my own proof based on the clue(using the **chain rule**) from that link.

First, let 
$$ 
H(X,Y) = trace(XY^TC) \qquad\qquad (1)
\\
f(A) = AB \qquad\qquad (2)
\\
g(A) = trace(ABA^TC) \qquad\qquad(3)
$$
$g(A)$ can be rewritten as:
$$
g(A) = H(f(A),A)$$
we know the chain rule:
$$
\nabla_A g(A) = \nabla_XH(X,Y)\cdot \nabla_Af(A)+\nabla_YH(X,Y)\cdot \nabla_AA 
$$
to simplify this equation, we need:
$$
\nabla_A trace(AB) = B^T \qquad\qquad (4)\\
trace(AB) = trace(BA) \qquad\qquad (5)\\
\nabla_{A^T}f(A) = [\nabla_Af(A)]^T \qquad\qquad(6)
$$
with (4), the first term 
$$
\nabla_XH(X,Y)\cdot \nabla_Af(A)
$$
can be write as:
$$
\nabla_X trace(XY^TC) \cdot \nabla_A f(A) = C^TY \cdot \nabla_A AB = C^TA \cdot \nabla_A AB
$$
and with(5)
the second term can be write as:
$$
\nabla_YH(X,Y)\cdot = \nabla_Y trace(XY^TC) \cdot \\
=\nabla_Y trace(Y^TCX)
$$
with (6):
$$
\nabla_Y trace(Y^TCX) = [\nabla_{Y^T} trace(Y^TCX)]^T 
$$
with (4):
$$
[\nabla_{Y^T} trace(Y^TCX)]^T = CX = CAB
$$
now I get 
$$
\nabla_A ( ABA^{T}C )  =  C^T A \cdot \nabla_A AB + CAB
$$

but i'm not sure that $\nabla_A AB = B^T$, can somebody show me why? or give my another proof?

Thank you for your honest suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is much easier if you use the [Frobenius Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) instead of the trace.

Write the objective function and find its differential
$$\eqalign{
  f &= {\rm tr}(ABA^TC) \cr
  &= I:ABA^TC \cr\cr
  df &= I:(dA)BA^TC + I:AB(dA^T)C \cr
  &= C^TAB^T:dA + B^TA^TC^T:dA^T \cr
  &= C^TAB^T:dA + CAB:dA \cr
  &= (C^TAB^T + CAB):dA \cr
}$$where some of the expressions were rearranged using these mixed product rules
$$\eqalign{
{\rm tr}(A^TBC) &= A:BC \cr
  &= AC^T:B \cr 
  &= B^TA:C \cr
  &= A^T:(BC)^T \cr
}$$which are derived from the cyclic property of the trace function.

Anyway, since $df=\big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}:dA\big),\,$ the gradient of the function must be
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial A} &= C^TAB^T + CAB \cr
}$$

Comment: Thank you frank. I failed to understand this $$ df = I:(dA)BA^TC + I:AB(dA^T)C $$ could you show me some derivative rules of Frobenius Inner Product? thank you!

Comment: More precisely, I can't understand why we keeps $ BA^TC $ fixed and differential $A$ in the first term and why we keeps $AB$ and $C$ fixed and differential $A^T$ in the second term. Thank you!

Comment: @Long The product rule $$d(X*Y)=dX*Y+X*dY$$ is valid for just about any type of matrix product. In particular, the rule is true for the Kronecker, Hadamard, Frobenius, and standard matrix product.

Comment: Two points confused me. 1, $A$ and $A^T$ consists of same elements. was it OK to regard it as $X$ and $Y$ in $$d(X*Y) = dX*Y + X*DY$$ to become  $$d(A*A^T) = dA*A^T + A*dA^T$$ 2. in the term $ABd(A^T)C$ $A^T$ is not in the left most position or right most position, how can I use $$d(X*Y) = dX*Y + X*DY$$ Thank you!

Comment: To expand a product of several terms, successively apply the binary rule, e.g. $$\eqalign{d(X*Y*Z)&=dX*(Y*Z) +X*d(Y*Z)\cr &=dX*(Y*Z) +X*(dY*Z+Y*dZ)\cr &=dX*Y*Z+X*dY*Z+X*Y*dZ \cr}$$