# Derivative of trace of matrix log: $\frac{\partial \ \mbox{tr}(AXB \ \mbox{log}(CXD))}{\partial X}$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, logarithms, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

It is well known that $\frac{\partial \ \mbox{tr}(\mbox{log}(X))}{\partial X} = X^{-T}$ ($\mbox{log}$ is matrix log, not element-wise), and I'm now trying to compute the following derivative:

$\frac{\partial \ \mbox{tr}(AX \ \mbox{log}(BX))}{\partial X}$.

More generally, I'm interested in the following derivative:

$\frac{\partial \ \mbox{tr}(AXB \ \mbox{log}(CXD))}{\partial X}$.

Can someone solve these problems? Can these derivatives be written in a closed-form? I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: As a physicist I find using indices on these sorts of problems can be very helpful. Consider $X^i_{\phantom ij}$ to be just a normal 1d variable, write out all the indices and then take the derivative.

Comment: See these hints: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096581/derivative-of-a-vector/1096655#1096655

Comment: Also possibly relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2302620/derivative-where-the-variable-is-a-matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f:X\rightarrow tr(AX\log(BX))$. For a general $X$ (s.t. $BX$ has no $<0$ eigenvalues), the derivative $Df_X$ has no closed-form

except if $A=B=I$; let $g:X\rightarrow tr(X\log(X))$. Then $Dg_X:H\rightarrow tr(H(\log(X)+I))$, and the gradient is $\nabla(g)(X)=\log(X^T)+I$.

or except if $AB=BA$ and $X=I$ ($B$ has no $<0$ eigenvalues); then $Df_I:H\rightarrow tr(AH\log(B)+ABHB^{-1})=tr(H(A\log(B)+A))$, and the gradient is $\nabla(f)(I)=A^T\log(B^T)+A^T$.

Comment: If $X$ is symmetric, then [http://www.matrixcalculus.org](http://www.matrixcalculus.org/) gives $\frac{d}{d X} \text{tr}(X \log(X)) = \log(X) + \text{matrix}(1)$, so they are wrong?