# Different proof for d(trace(A'BAC))?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to proove a common thing with a slight twist($A$ and $A^{T}$ are switched) $$ \nabla_A \operatorname{trace}( A^{T}BAC )  = BAC + B^T AC^T$$. I'm assuming all matrices here are square and of same size.
I have already looked at the question [Proof for the funky trace derivative : $d (\operatorname{trace} (ABA'C))$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138267/proof-for-the-funky-trace-derivative-d-operatornametrace-abac/138618#138618) , but in the upvoted answer I don't understand how the chain rule is supposed to work with matrices, especially I don't see why the derivative(and what kind of derivative should that be? It can't be $\nabla_A$ because that is only defined for scalar w.r.t matrix.) of $AB$ w.r.t $A$ should be $B^{T}$.

Therefore I tried to proove this on my own. I believe I'm making a mistake and can't seem to find it. Let's calculate the differential:
$$d tr(A^{T}BAC) = tr(d(A^{T}BAC))=tr(d(A^{T})BAC+A^{T}Bd(A)C)\\ =tr(d(A^{T})BAC)+tr(A^{T}Bd(A)C)=tr((d(A))^{T}BAC)+tr(A^{T}Bd(A)C)\\=tr(C^{T}A^{T}B^{T}d(A))+tr(A^{T}Bd(A)C)=tr(C^{T}A^{T}B^{T}d(A))+tr(CA^{T}Bd(A))\\=tr((C^{T}A^{T}B^{T}+CA^{T}B)d(A))$$
I have found a rule to convert from differential to derivative form. $$dy=tr(AdX) \quad \Rightarrow \frac{\partial y}{\partial X}=A $$. If this rule is correct, I will get my answear transposed as opposed to what I was trying to prove. Can you please help me spot the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a colon (:) to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. 
$$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
Then the rule to convert between the differential to gradient is
$$dy=A:dX \,\,\Longleftrightarrow\,\, \frac{\partial y}{\partial X}=A$$
In addition, two simple properties of the trace
$$\eqalign{
{\rm tr}(AB) &= {\rm tr}(BA) \cr
{\rm tr}(A^T) &= {\rm tr}(A) \cr
}$$
give rise to many rules for rearranging the Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
A:BC
 &= B^TA:C \cr
 &= AC^T:B \cr
 &= BC:A \cr
}$$
Applying these tools to the current problem yields
$$\eqalign{
 y &= A:BAC \cr\cr
dy
 &= dA:BAC + A:B\,dA\,C \cr
 &= BAC:dA + B^TAC^T:dA \cr
 &= (BAC + B^TAC^T):dA \cr\cr
\frac{\partial y}{\partial A} &= BAC + B^TAC^T \cr
}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Even if you provided a different proof that i wanted, I believe you have shown me the mistake. You used the conversion rule as follows $dy=A:dX \,\,\Longleftrightarrow\,\, \frac{\partial y}{\partial X}=A$. But translating that to my notation, that means  $dy=tr(A^{T}dX) \,\,\Longleftrightarrow\,\, \frac{\partial y}{\partial X}=A$, which solves my problem. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's an accurate translation of my result back into trace notation. The question of $A$ vs $A^T$ is referred to as the [layout convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions). Pick the one that you like and stick with it.