# Gradient of $C \mapsto\frac{1}{2}\left\lVert CA - BC \right\rVert_F^2$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

Given the matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$, let the scalar field $f : \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$$ f(C) := \frac{1}{2}\left\lVert CA - BC \right\rVert_F^2 $$

What is the gradient $\nabla f$?

---

I am trying to differentiate this function w.r.t. to $C$  but I cannot find a way to manipulate the expression that would enable me to do so. I've also tried a definition of derivative adapted in this case but I don't endup with something useful at first glance. I endup with a linear map $df(C)$ defined by the expression

$$
df(C)E = \text{trace} \left\{ (CA -BC)^T (EA - BE)\right\} = \left\langle CA -BC,EA-BE\right\rangle
$$

which then leads to me to

$$
df(C) = \left\langle AA^TC^T - AC^TB^T - A^TC^TB + C^TB^TB, \cdot \right\rangle
$$

Is this expression correct?

Comment: If you're planning to use the gradient to perform some sort of gradient descent, don't bother. It's obvious that $f(C)$ achieves its global minimum at $C=0.\;$ If you put another term in the norm, i.e. $\left\|CA-BC-M\right\|_F^2,\:$ then you'd have a [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation), which is a more interesting problem.

Comment: I won't bother. But I have a cost function whose one term is $f(C)$. I the Sylvester equarions the matrices are square which is not my case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let

$$ f({\bf X}) := \frac12 \left\| {\bf X} {\bf A} - {\bf B} {\bf X} \right\|_{\text{F}}^2 $$

Using the definition of the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) and the [cyclic property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Cyclic_property) of the trace,

$$ \nabla_{{\bf X}} f({\bf X}) =  \cdots = \color{blue}{({\bf X} {\bf A} - {\bf B} {\bf X}) {\bf A}^\top - {\bf B}^\top ({\bf X} {\bf A} - {\bf B} {\bf X})} $$

---

**Addendum**

Suppose that we would like to find where the gradient vanishes.  We then have the following linear matrix equation.

$$ ({\bf X} {\bf A} - {\bf B} {\bf X}) {\bf A}^\top - {\bf B}^\top ({\bf X} {\bf A} - {\bf B} {\bf X}) = {\bf O}_{m \times n} $$

[Vectorizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) both sides, we obtain the following homogeneous linear system

$$ \left( \left( {\bf A} {\bf A}^\top \otimes {\bf I}_m \right) - \left( {\bf A} \otimes {\bf B} \right) - \left( {\bf A} \otimes {\bf B} \right)^\top + \left( {\bf I}_n \otimes {\bf B}^\top {\bf B}\right) \right) \operatorname{vec} ({\bf X}) = {\bf 0}_{mn} $$

---

**Related**

- [Gradient of squared Frobenius norm of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2128462/339790)
- [Gradient of $A \mapsto \operatorname{trace} (A B A' C)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/138267/339790)

Comment: But is it possible to set it up in a way that I can solve for $X$? Also I think my expression is equivalent to yours, unless I made a mistake.

Comment: @user8469759 You can solve using vectorization. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)

Comment: @user8469759 Yes, I think we obtained the same gradient, though you did not write in terms of $\bf XA - BX$

Comment: @obareey I am not sure how to use it to obtain a formula however. Would be useful if someone showed me.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo so it comes from some properties of vectorization

Comment: One question, your last expression. Can't it be converted back to something like $ZX = 0$?

Comment: @user8469759 If it can, I do not know how